# Check for equal Associated Types in where clause

Tags: generics, rust

Consider these two traits:

```
trait Iterator {
   type Item;

   fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}
```

and

```
trait SeeekingIterator {
    type Item;

    fn next(&mut self, other: &Self::Item) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}
```

Now assume, I wanted to implement something like `std::iter::Peekable` for structs that implement both `Iterator` and `SeekingIterator`.

This would look a bit like:

```
struct PeekableSeekable<I>  where
    I: Iterator + SeekingIterator
{
    iter: I,
    peeked: Option<<I as Iterator>::Item>        
}
```

It would implement

```
fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<&<I as Iterator>::Item>;
```

and

```
fn peek_seek(&mut self, other: &<I as SeekingIterator>::Item) -> Option<&<I as SeekingIterator>::Item>
```

The problem now is, that this would only work if `<I as Iterator>::Item == <I as SeekingIterator>::Item`.

I don't know of a way to express this inside a `where` clause. 
I'm faking it by using

```
Option<<I as Iterator>::Item>: From<Option<<I as SeekingIterator>::Item>>
```

and

```
Option<<I as SeekingIterator>::Item>: From<Option<<I as Iterator>::Item>>
```

And then calling `Option::from` when a transformation is needed. This seems a bit ugly and I am wondering if this problem could be solved more concisely.

Comment: Please consider creating a [MCVE] in the future. It was very difficult to guess at what your `impl` block contained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reference one trait from the other trait constraint:

```
struct PeekableSeekable<I>
    where I: Iterator
{
    iter: I,
    peeked: Option<I::Item>,
}

impl<I> PeekableSeekable<I>
    where I: Iterator<Item = <I as SeekingIterator>::Item> + SeekingIterator
{
    // Implement
}
```